# Sending 'NSNumber *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'double')

Tags: ios, cllocation

```
NSNumber * latitude =  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[cityDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"coordinates.latitude"]doubleValue]];

      NSNumber * longitude =  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[cityDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"coordinates.longitude"]doubleValue]];


    CLLocation *listingLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
```

I am getting the following error on line # 3 above:

```
Sending 'NSNumber *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'double')
```

I know it is because I am trying to pass a NSNumber to a place where it expects a double. But casting is not working due to ARC?

Comment: Note that you aren't actually casting anything in that code.  (It wouldn't help if you did but, in terms of identifying the current problem, that's not it.)

Comment: not sure who is down voting but it is apparent someone is bored. I tried to upvote all those that answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `[cityDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"coordinates.latitude"]` is already giving you an `NSNumber` object. Why convert that to a double and then create a new `NSNumber`?

You could just do:

```
NSNumber *latitude = [cityDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"coordinates.latitude"];
NSNumber *longitude = [cityDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"coordinates.longitude"];
CLLocation *listingLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude doubleValue] longitude:[longitude doubleValue]];
```

If it turns out that `[cityDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"coordinates.latitude"]` is actually returning an `NSString` and not an `NSNumber`, then do this:

```
CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[cityDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"coordinates.latitude"] doubleValue];
CLLocationDegrees longitude = [[cityDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"coordinates.longitude"] doubleValue];
CLLocation *listingLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are sending type NSNumber to a parameter of double. You could consider changing it to `CLLocationDegree`'s or `double`, but if you are using it elsewhere or storing it with core data I would leave it as `NSNumber`.

```
CLLocation *listingLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude doubleValue] longitude:[longitude doubleValue]];
```